# Distribute a Java LWJGL program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, native, lwjgl

I'm currently learning [LWJGL](https://www.lwjgl.org) on Intellij Idea. I can run the official HelloWorld code with my IDE's built-in run tool but I would love to **compress my code into a jar file**.

I followed this [wiki](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/Distributing_Your_LWJGL_Application.html) with my files I downloaded from [here](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize) (bundle zip).

I created a jar build system via Intellij Idea's "Artifacts" and can run a simple program but still not a LWJGL one.

I'm a bit lost with native jars which I need to include.

Do I need to include native jars as a library, do I need to copy them next to my jar?

Please explain me, a beginner, to build this jar. The less tools such as gradle I use, the better, I want to learn.

Comment: I already zipped a java program into a jar with a terminal, but after some research I found out that building more complex projects manually was a nightmare, but if you have good tutorials to suggest I will not refuse it.

Comment: I'm not not interested in hearing anything about using the idiomatically correct tools, I just don't want to climb too high in abstraction. And if you want to explain me how to do this with a terminal you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build my jar with a terminal.
Everything I will explain works in a single folder, no subfolder for packages etc.. (for simplicity)

You will need a minimal ZIP bundle from [here](https://www.lwjgl.org/customize), including the natives corresponding to the OS(s) you want to distribute for.

- Compile with `javac -cp ".;./lwjgl.jar;./lwjgl-opengl.jar;./lwjgl-glfw.jar" Main.java` (replace ; by : if you are on unix system)
- Create a manifest file `myManifest.txt` containing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ./lwjgl.jar ./lwjgl-glfw.jar ./lwjgl-opengl.jar ./lwjgl-natives-windows.jar
Main-Class: Main
```

Do not forget the blank line at the end.

- Jar it with `jar -cvfm MyJar.jar .\myManifest.txt .\Main.class`

You can now run your jar by double clicking it, you will need all .jar files in this folder, .java, .class and manifest files can be removed.